# Issue with - >Share file in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

We wanted to provide the share option to our app, so that we can upload files from the SD card to our app i.e. similar to that of share option in Onedrive/Notepad etc.

In package.appxmainfest we add share Target in declaration and checked support any file type. In the case of tablet it works fine. Where as for the phone the app gets listed in share, but when we select our app it getting crashed.

On the tab, when we try to do a share it is able to call the below function,
protected override void OnShareTargetActivated (ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args) {}. This event is present in the app.xaml file 
where in the case of phone this function is not getting invoked and also the app gets crashed.

Can we have some pointers as how we can resolve the crash, we have followed the steps provided in windows doc.

Adding the code snippet

```
protected override async void 
OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
    var absoluteUri = "";
    var shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
    if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
    {
        var uri = await shareOperation.Data.GetWebLinkAsync();
        if (uri != null)
        {
            absoluteUri = uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
    }
    //Notify shareOperation that we are completed as soon as possible
    shareOperation.ReportCompleted();

    var rootFrame = new Frame();
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), absoluteUri);
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the link of doc from where have you implemented ?

Comment: http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=507

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: protected? is that correct? I would say a function called from outside should be public (seeing it from the design standpoint at least...)

Comment: when we change from protected  to public we get the below error 

Error 1 'App10.App.OnShareTargetActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.OnShareTargetActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs)' D:\Source Safe\Windows\testapp\App10\App10\App10.Shared\App.xaml.cs

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?